# How is the standard deviation of random effects estimated?

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, variance, random-effects-model

For example, the sd of the random intercept reported by lme4 when I use lmer or glmer is much higher than if I just calculated the sd on the list of intercepts generated from `ranef`. Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that your model is something like
$$
y_{ij} = \beta + u_j + \varepsilon_{ij}
$$
where $u_j \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2_u)$, for $j=1,\ldots,m$, are the random intercepts and $\varepsilon_{ij} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2_\varepsilon)$ are the error terms. To keep this simple, let's assume that $i=1,\ldots,n$, i.e. there are $n$ observations in each of the $m$ groups/clusters.

Estimating the within-cluster variance ($\sigma^2_\varepsilon$) from the residuals is easy; we just take
$$
\hat{\sigma}^2_\varepsilon=\frac{1}{m(n-1)}\sum_{i,j}(y_{ij} - \bar{y}_{.j})^2
$$
where $\bar{y}_{.j}$ is the sample mean of the $j$th cluster. The denominator $m(n-1)$ comes from the fact that we lose one degree of freedom in each cluster.

To estimate the variance of the random intercepts ($\sigma^2_u$), we need to work a bit harder. The maximum-likelihood estimator is
$$
\hat{\sigma}^2_u=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{j}(\bar{y}_{.j} - \bar{y}_{..})^2 - \frac{1}{n}\hat{\sigma}^2_\varepsilon
$$
where $\bar{y}_{..}$ is the (global) sample mean. Why the two terms? The first one looks at the squared difference between the mean of the $j$th cluster and the overall mean, while the second one is an adjustment for the within-cluster variance.

Comment: In practice, most software libraries for random-effects models report the restricted maximum-likelihood (REML) estimate of the random intercepts. This is similar to the ML estimate above, but we divide the first term by $m-1$ instead of $m$. The advantage is that the REML estimator is unbiased when the data are balanced (i.e., the setup we have here).

Try calculating this for your data and comparing with the model output.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I should clarify, I would like to know why the standard deviation of the conditional modes (BLUPS) of the intercepts for the groups is so different from the (RE)ML estimated standard deviation of the intercepts for the groups.

Comment: Right, I see what you mean. Are you taking into account the shrinkage factor? The BLUP of the $j$th random effect is $\hat{\lambda}_j \hat{u}_j$ (where $\hat{\lambda}_j$ is the shrinkage for the $j$th cluster). In our case all the $\hat{\lambda}_j$ are the same, so the sample variance of the BLUPS is $\hat{\lambda} \hat{\sigma}^2_u$.

Comment: That's a good point, I didn't take into account the shrinkage factor. Does the SD reported by the model for the random effects then ignore or take into account the shrinkage factor?